# How can a mac admin access my laptop by files while I’m offline?

Tags: mac, applications, filesystem, administrator, documentation

I have a company laptop and my Mac admin was able to update my application apps, remove unnecessary apps, and clear old files in my document folder. However, he was able to do all of this while my mac was offline.

Only way I can think the admin would be able to do this is if he had some kind of back up system in place before my mac went offline? I didn’t  notice any cloud or syncing service on my Mac.

Comment: You may have to accurately define 'offline'… as for many devices these days, that may need to be '50 miles from civilisation'.

Comment: Many of those "control software packages" that companies install will check and update during the boot process before you even complete logging in.

Comment: @Tetsujin By offline, I mean no internet at all.

Comment: @SolarMike Thank you for the help Solar Mike. I've did some more research and seems that they might be using an MDM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are completely offline even during boot (being certain that your bios isn't connecting to internet during boot), then your mac is probably using some version of an online filesystem (NFS) that stores all of its files in the cloud. However, the more probable answer, is that your admin is using MDM, and during a mac os boot, your bios connected to wifi, and the MDM controller automatically modified your files on boot.